# JavaScript selection/range framework

Tags: javascript, dom, range, selection

I've been working with selection/range objects, and because to the incredible amount of inconsistencies between browsers for specific selection/range stuff (even more than the DOM) I was wondering if there was a framework that would help me get through them.

Comment: Have you seen http://code.google.com/p/ierange/ ?

Comment: Roatin, this is exactly what i was looking for! Can you make it a question so I can upvote you? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Made an answer by request ;)

Take a look at [IERange](http://code.google.com/p/ierange/):

> IERange is a feature-complete
>   implementation of W3C [DOM Ranges](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) for
>   Internet Explorer, allowing users to
>   write one cross-browser version of
>   their range manipulation code.

Supports Range APIs:

- `document.createRange()`
- `startContainer`, `startOffset`, `endContainer`, `endOffset`, `commonAncestorContainer`, `collapsed`
- `setStart()`, `setEnd()`, `setStartBefore()`, `setStartAfter()`, `setEndBefore()`, `setEndAfter()`, `selectNode()`, `selectNodeContents()`, `collapse()`
- `insertNode()`, `surroundContents()`
- `extractContents()`, `cloneContents()`, `deleteContents()`
- `compareBoundaryPoints()`, `cloneRange()`, `createContextualFragment()`, `toString()`

Supports Selection APIs:

- Range support (Webkit-style)
- `window.getSelection()`
- `addRange()`, `removeAllRanges()`, `getRangeAt()`, `toString()`

Comment: IERange's biggest strength is its algorithms for expressing a `TextRange` in terms of nodes and offsets (as a Range does) and converting such and object back into a `TextRange`. However, it cannot fully abstract away the differences between the two: for example, the underlying `TextRange` will change in response to changes in the DOM while the `IERange` built upon it will not reflect these changes. There are also discrepancies between how the user selection is represented as a Range, which are down to the browser. [continued]

Comment: Also note that creating an `IERange` is hugely slower than getting a DOM Range in other browsers. None of these are the library's fault; it's simply the nature of the problem. In short, best use with care and knowledge of the abstraction `IERange` represents.

Answer (score 13):

I've written a new range/selection library called [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) that is similar in concept to IERange but goes quite a lot further. <strike>The core is pretty much complete and [currently available to download](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/downloads/list). I'm currently bugfixing and documenting it and it should be only be a few weeks before a full release.</strike>

**UPDATE 31 August 2011**

Rangy is now stable and at version 1.2 ([downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/downloads/list)).

Comment: Thanks for your great work on Rangy Tim Down. I'm using your lib in my new project and already have send you a bug report. I think it would be a good idea to create a mailing list, so that it is possible to discuss issues/features and suggest new features (maybe with a patch). Eg., I'm currently trying to get a startOffset and endOffset for the commonAncestorContainer rather than start/end containers. This would be a helpful feature I believe.

Answer (score 1):

[fieldselection](http://labs.0xab.cd/jquery/fieldselection/0.2.3-test/test.html) is a very usable jquery plugin for selection/range manipulation.